# Using filter with count

Tags: r, filter, count, dplyr

I'm trying to filter row using the `count()` helper.
What I would like as output are all the rows where the `map %>% count(StudentID) = 3`.

For instance in the df below, it should take out all the rows with StudentID 10016 and 10020 as they are only 2 instances of these and I want 3.

```
StudentID StudentGender Grade     TermName      ScaleName TestRITScore
100             M     9    Fall 2010    Language Usage          217
100             M    10    2011-2012    Language Usage          220
100             M     9    Fall 2010    Reading                 210
10016           M     6    Fall 2010    Language Usage          217
10016           M     6    Fall 2010    Mathematics             210
10020           F     7    Fall 2010    Language Usage          210
10020           F     7    Fall 2010    Mathematics             213
10022           F     8    Fall 2010    Language Usage          232
10022           F     9    2011-2012    Language Usage          240
10022           F     8    Fall 2010    Mathematics             242
```

if I do:

```
count(df, StudentID)
```

then it only gives me a df with 2 columns, but I want to keep all the columns of my df.  thats's why I think I should use filter.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I don't think `count` is what you looking for. Try `n()` instead:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(StudentID) %>%
  filter(n() == 3)

# Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
# Groups: StudentID
# 
#   StudentID StudentGender Grade  TermName      ScaleName TestRITScore
# 1       100             M     9 Fall 2010 Language Usage          217
# 2       100             M    10 2011-2012 Language Usage          220
# 3       100             M     9 Fall 2010 Reading                 210
# 4     10022             F     8 Fall 2010 Language Usage          232
# 5     10022             F     9 2011-2012 Language Usage          240
# 6     10022             F     8 Fall 2010 Mathematics             242
```

Comment: `count` is most definitely in the bleeding edge `dplyr` but it's intended purpose is not what the OP needs. You're spot-on.

Comment: Not trying to be snarky, but search the PDF for "`count(`"

Comment: @hrbrmstr yeah just did. I probably have an old version of `dplyr`

Comment: @hrbrmstr, anyway, I fixed the title, as I had an older version of `dplyr` that didn't contain `count`

Comment: David, the count() will only work if your R version is also updated (ie. >=3.1), otherwise the dplyr version stays at 0.2.

Comment: @Franky, interesting.

Comment: Another option would be `df %>% semi_join(df %>% count(StudentID) %>% filter(n > 3))`

Comment: @hadley, would the semi join create another copy of df in memory?