# How to conditionally delete group-specific factor levels in R

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, data-manipulation

I have a data frame where I want to filter out the Month values if the count of its associated Index is < 2.

```
ID = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5))
Month = c(
  1,
  1,
  2,
  2,
  3,
  1,
  2,
  2,
  3,
  3
)
Index = c("X1", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X3")
df = data.frame(ID, Month, Index, stringsAsFactors =  FALSE)
df$Month <- as.factor(df$Month)
df
```

Here, X3 and X1 only occur once for A and B respectively so those rows would be deleted.

But if I try to filter my data using `%in%` for X3 and X1 they will also get removed from the other ID values.

The deletion should only be group specific.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using filter with count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573285/using-filter-with-count)

Comment: There's a *very* in-depth comparison of different methods that might help here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43110349/5325862. Also many options here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20204257/5325862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by the columns and `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Month, Index) %>%
  filter(n() >1)
```